# D3js projection issues when fitting to BBox

Tags: d3.js

*(My code is at the end)*

My goal is to display a country map (provided in a topojson file) which automatically scale and translate to fit into an area and then display few dots on it, representing some cities (given their lat/long coordinates).

First part was easy. I found (don't remember if it was on SO or on bl.ocks.org) that we can use bounds to compute scale and translate. That works perfectly and my country adapt to its parent area.

**First Question:** Why the country doesn't behave the same if I scale/translate it with its *transform attribute* or with `projection.scale().translate()` ? I mean, when I use *transform attribute* the country adapts perfectly whereas `projection.scale().translate()` displays a small country in a corner.

Second part is displaying some cities on my map. My cities has coordinates (which are real ones) :

```
var cities = {
    features: [
    {
        'type':'Feature',
        'geometry':{
            'type':'Polygon',
            'coordinates': [2.351828, 48.856578] // Longitude, Latitude
        },
        'properties':{}
    },
    {
        'type':'Feature',
        'geometry':{
            'type':'Polygon',
            'coordinates': [5.726945, 45.187778] // Longitude, Latitude
        },
        'properties':{}
    },

};
```

When I try to apply scale and translate parameters (to adapt with my country which has been scaled and translated) either with `projection.scale().translate()` or with *transform attribute* my cities are far far away from where they should be.

**Second Question:** Why I cannot use same scale/translate parameters on country and cities ? How can I properly display my cities where they should be ?

```
function computeAutoFitParameters(bounds, width, height) {
    var dx        = bounds[1][0] - bounds[0][0];
    var dy        = bounds[1][1] - bounds[0][1];
    var x         = (bounds[0][0] + bounds[1][0]) / 2;
    var y         = (bounds[0][1] + bounds[1][1]) / 2;
    var scale     = 0.9 / Math.max(dx / width, dy / height);
    var translate = [width / 2 - scale * x, height / 2 - scale * y];

    return {
        scale    : scale,
        translate: translate
    };
}

// element is the HTML area where the country has to fit.
var height      = element.height();
var width       = element.width();
var projection  = d3.geo.miller();
var path        = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

// data is my country (a topojson file with BBox)
var topojsonCountry = topojson.feature(data, data.objects[country.id]).features;
var bounds          = path.bounds(topojsonCountry[0]);
var params          = computeAutoFitParameters(bounds, width, height);
var scale           = params.scale;
var translate       = params.translate;

var svg = d3.select(element[0]).append('svg')
          .attr('width', width + 'px')
          .attr('height', height + 'px');

svg.append('g')
.selectAll('path')
.data(topojsonCountry)
.enter()
.append('path')
    .attr('d', path)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + translate + ')scale(' + scale + ')');

svg.selectAll('circle')
.data(cities.features) // city is defined in the code above
.enter()
.append('circle')
    .attr('transform', function(d) {
        return 'translate(' + projection(d.geometry.coordinates) + ')';
    )
    .attr('r', '6px');
```

EDIT: I had removed too much code to simplify it. It's fixed now. The difference is that I have an array of cities to display rather than just one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this code working? Shouldn't it be `return 'translate(' + projection(city.geometries.coordinates) + ')';`?

Comment: You're right. When cleaning up my code before posting it, I removed too much code. It's good. The new code is working but does not resolve my scale/translate issues (for my cities) which are separated from few millimeters while they should be distant from few centimeters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I had to add null parameters to my projection. To sum up :

1. Create a minimal `projection` (and a `path`)
2. Apply null `scale` and `translate` parameters to the `projection` : `projection.scale(1).translate([0, 0])`
3. Compute real `scale` and `translate` parameters according to the bounding box
4. Display the country's map as before (no changes here)
5. Set computed `scale` and `translate` parameters to the projection : `projection.scale(params.scale).translate(params.translate);`
6. Draw the cities dots.

`

```
// element is the HTML area where the country has to fit.
var height      = element.height();
var width       = element.width();
var projection  = d3.geo.miller();
var path        = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

projection.scale(1).translate([0, 0]) // This is new

// data is my country (a topojson file with BBox)
var topojsonCountry = topojson.feature(data, data.objects[country.id]).features;
var bounds          = path.bounds(topojsonCountry[0]);
var params          = computeAutoFitParameters(bounds, width, height);

var svg = d3.select(element[0]).append('svg')
    .attr('width', width + 'px')
    .attr('height', height + 'px');

svg.append('g')
    .selectAll('path')
    .data(topojsonCountry)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
        .attr('d', path)
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + params.translate + ')scale(' + params.scale + ')');

projection.scale(params.scale).translate(params.translate); // This is new

svg.selectAll('circle')
    .data(cities.features)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('transform', function(d) {
        return 'translate(' + projection(d.geometry.coordinates) + ')';
    })
    .attr('r', '6px')
    .attr('fill', 'red');
```